# Saving a set of SQL results from a query into different csv files

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, stored-procedures

The requirements of my task is to take a query that asks for a language/region(ex. french) and outputs a table of data that needs to be translated. There is 9 languages so I have to run 9 queries, paste and format into excel, and save them all.

Is there a way, since I am only changing 1 variable within the query 9 times, I can have SQL run the query 9 times each time saving the result into a csv into a pre-specified folder?

I am new to SQL scripts like this and would appreciate the logic needed to accomplish this (report? stored procedure?). It cannot be a simple pull from the table because there is lots of specification in the WHERE clause as to what data to not show.

Comment: *"There is 9 languages so I have to run 9 queries, paste and format into excel, and save them all."* Why 9 queries? Why not 1 parametrised one? You say there are "lots of specifications in the `WHERE`" but then fail to give us any of those requirements. What are you actually asking here? What have you tried so far? Why isn't it working? Sample data and expected results along with all of that will help us help you.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a sql server question - presumably you've some host language that you are using to connect, query, and save the results as csv?  for us to help you you'll probably need to post the whole script you're using and tag it appropriately.

Comment: You can use `bcp` to easily export data to a CSV file, your existing query should be in a procedure that takes a parameter that determines the language and you can then invoke it appropriately and set the desired output file with a simple `case` or lookup.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Python. You can run for loop to change 1 variable in your query and then use fetchdata to fetch that data from query and store it in a dataframe and that dataframe can be stored in the CSV file